# Template does not exsit error happens

Tags: django

I am making Django app.Django version is 1.8 .
I wrote in views.py

```
dir_path = "../static/template/"
if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
    os.makedirs(dir_path)

html_path = dir_path + "test.html"

if os.path.exists(html_path):
    template = loader.get_template(html_path)
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request))
```

When I run it,Template does not exsit error happens.But file is existed in the directory, so I really cannot understand why this error happens.Is relative path not good?How should I fix this?

Comment: templte folder will not the subfolder of static. static and tempates will be different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django use own template engines and you don't have to set your template dir in static.

You have to set up `TEMPLTES` settings. And if you need, just add your template dirs in settings. like below

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/your/own/path'
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

django automatically and dynamically find your template in your template dirs and base template dirs (inside your project and/or app's template dir)

Read django template docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/) and it will be helped a lot.